How do I use custom ThreadPoolExecutor in a verticle?
I have recently started using Vert.x. Earlier I was using Play framework. In play, I was using Actor system with a custom MessageDispatcherConfigurator to use a custom ThreadPoolExecutor, which propagates thread context while switching executors, or switching threads in same executor pool.
CustomDispatcherConfigurator
public class CustomDispatcherConfigurator extends MessageDispatcherConfigurator {

    private final CustomDispatcher instance;

    public CustomDispatcherConfigurator(Config config, DispatcherPrerequisites prerequisites) {
        super(config, prerequisites);
        Config threadPoolConfig = config.getConfig("thread-pool-executor");
        int fixedPoolSize = threadPoolConfig.getInt("fixed-pool-size");
        instance = new CustomDispatcher(
                this,
                config.getString("id"),
                config.getInt("throughput"),
                Duration.create(config.getDuration("throughput-deadline-time", TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS), TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS),
                (id, threadFactory) -> () -> new CustomThreadPoolExecutor(fixedPoolSize,
                        fixedPoolSize,
                        threadPoolConfig.getDuration("keep-alive-time", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                        new LinkedBlockingDeque<>(),
                        new ThreadFactory() {
                            private int threadId = 1;

                            @Override
                            public Thread newThread(@NotNull Runnable r) {
                                Thread thread = new Thread(r);
                                thread.setName(config.getString("name") + "-" + threadId++);
                                return thread;
                            }
                        }),
                Duration.create(config.getDuration("shutdown-timeout", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        );
    }

    @Override
    public MessageDispatcher dispatcher() {
        return instance;
    }

}

class CustomDispatcher extends Dispatcher {

    public CustomDispatcher(MessageDispatcherConfigurator _configurator,
            String id,
            int throughput,
            Duration throughputDeadlineTime,
            ExecutorServiceFactoryProvider executorServiceFactoryProvider,
            scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration shutdownTimeout) {
        super(_configurator, id, throughput, throughputDeadlineTime, executorServiceFactoryProvider, shutdownTimeout);
    }

}

CustomThreadPoolExecutor
public class CustomThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
    
    public CustomThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize,
            int maximumPoolSize,
            long keepAliveTime,
            @NotNull TimeUnit unit,
            @NotNull BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue);
    }
    
    public CustomThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize,
            int maximumPoolSize,
            long keepAliveTime,
            @NotNull TimeUnit unit,
            @NotNull BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue,
            @NotNull ThreadFactory threadFactory) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue, threadFactory);
    }

    public CustomThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize,
            int maximumPoolSize,
            long keepAliveTime,
            @NotNull TimeUnit unit,
            @NotNull BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue,
            @NotNull RejectedExecutionHandler handler) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue, handler);
    }

    public CustomThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize,
            int maximumPoolSize,
            long keepAliveTime,
            @NotNull TimeUnit unit,
            @NotNull BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue,
            @NotNull ThreadFactory threadFactory,
            @NotNull RejectedExecutionHandler handler) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue, threadFactory, handler);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> @NotNull Future<T> submit(@NotNull Callable<T> task) {
        return super.submit(ContextUtility.wrapWithContext(task));
    }

    @Override
    public <T> @NotNull Future<T> submit(@NotNull Runnable task, T result) {
        return super.submit(ContextUtility.wrapWithContext(task), result);
    }

    @Override
    public @NotNull Future<?> submit(@NotNull Runnable task) {
        return super.submit(ContextUtility.wrapWithContext(task));
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(@NotNull Runnable task) {
        super.execute(ContextUtility.wrapWithContext(task));
    }
}

I want to use the same CustomThreadPoolExecutor class instead of the default ThreadPoolExecutor, in all my Verticles. How do I do so? I explored about an SPI ExecutorServiceFactory, and I implemented it by using my CustomThreadPoolExecutor in its createExecutor method but I don't know how to use this CustomExecutorServiceFactory while deploying my Verticles.
CustomExecutorServiceFactory
public class CustomExecutorServiceFactory implements ExecutorServiceFactory {
    @Override
    public void init(VertxBuilder builder) {
        ExecutorServiceFactory.super.init(builder);
    }

    @Override
    public ExecutorService createExecutor(ThreadFactory threadFactory, Integer concurrency, Integer maxConcurrency) {
        return new CustomThreadPoolExecutor(concurrency, maxConcurrency, 10L, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS,
                new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(), threadFactory);
    }
}


Vert.x has the behavior you desire already built in:

Vert.x guarantees that for normal Verticles, not Worker Verticles, the executing thread stays always the same. So, from the moment a Verticle's start() method is executed until its end() method is executed, it will be always the same thread. There may be other Verticles however, which share that same thread.
Vert.x also assigns a context to the Verticle, which holds the reference to that thread, and which can be used to share data between handlers in the same context. Each Verticle has its own context instance, i.e. it is not shared. However, accessing normal members (instance variables) of the Verticle class is way faster.

You can get the current context of a Verticle by calling vertx.getOrCreateContext().

My enquiry might sound confusing, or even stupid as I have just started using vert.x. So, I have a HttpServerVerticle and DatabaseClientVerticle, both worker verticles deployed from a MainVerticle. HttpServerVerticle is responsible for serving requests. I want each API request to have its separate context, which can be passed on to DatabaseClientVerticle when any db related task is required, and the context to be cleared after the request is completed.

It’s never stupid... I wouldn’t make HttpServerVerticle a Worker Verticle. Keep it as a normal one because you will want requests to be served on the event loop. In your request handler you’ll have a RequestContext (at least with Vert.x Web module) that you’ll use to eventually answer/complete a request. Also in your request handler, you’ll trigger whatever action needs to be done (database, Kafka, file etc.), each returning a Future<?>. On completion of all those Futures, you’ll also complete the RequestContext, e.g. by calling end() or fail(). Hope that clarifies a bit.
